# RequireJS, not loading jQuery proberly

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I know there are many RequireJS topics with modules that don't load but none of them have helped me :-S

My "start.js" file looks like

```
requirejs.config({
paths: {
    jquery: 'js/jquery-2.2.0.min'
}
});

define(['lib/class', 'lib/underscore.min', 'lib/stacktrace'], function() {
    require(["main"]);
});
```

My HTML file contains in the head

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

This is the only script load in the whole HTML page

My main function only contains

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    alert("hello");
});
```

But when I load my page I get

```
Error: Script error for "jquery", needed by: main http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

I've tried using base-urls, other locations... but the "alias" is just being ignored. While if I do

```
define(['jquery-2.2.0.min'], function($) {
    alert("hello");
});
```

It just works fine.

Anyone has an idea? My network log also says he never tries to fetch jquery-2.2.0.min but always the wrong "jquery" file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `data-main` to load your `start.js` file:

```
<script data-main="js/start" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

As you have it in your question, nothing loads `start.js` and thus your RequireJS configuration is not loaded.

Comment: Now I just feel stupid, thanks for seeing the obvious